# Getting output of wpf effect (hlsl shader effect)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hlsl

Is there a way to get the output of an effect in wpf? Having to render the visual that the effect is applied to takes too long. Is there an accessible framebuffer for the wpf effects?